# ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18

Tags: php, reactjs

me encuentro con el problema de que `render` ya no es soportado en `react 18`, hago la actualización cambiando

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

por cualquiera de estos 2 (ya los probe)

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App />)
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('#app')).render(<App />)
```

Y me sale el siguiente error

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
```

Alguna solución para esto?
Adjunto el `codigo` completo de mi `App`

```
const App = () => {
  ///page/index/getInformationPage
  //levar la info de la pagina links redes sociales info footer
  const infoUrl = `page/index/getInformationPage`;
  const [infoPage, setInfoPage] = React.useState();

  const fetchInfoPage = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(infoUrl);

    const data = await response.json();

    setInfoPage(data);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchInfoPage();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter>
      <Navigation {...infoPage} />
      <Help />
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/contacto" exact component={Contacto} />
      <Route path="/convenios" exact component={Convenios} />
      <Route path="/nosotros" exact component={Nosotros} />
      <Route path="/portafolio" exact component={Portafolio} />
      <Route
        path="/portafolio/detalle/:section"
        exact
        component={PortafolioDetail}
      />
      <Route path="/sedes" exact component={Sedes} />
      <Route path="/pqrs" exact component={PqrsIndex} />
      <Route path="/noticias" exact component={NoticiaAll} />
      <Route
        path="/noticias/detail/:newDetail"
        exact
        component={NoticiaDetail}
      />
      <Footer {...infoPage} />
    </ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

No tengo como tal un `index.js` ya que el proyecto es una incorporación con un `framework` en `php`, tengo el archivo `page.php` donde allí pongo mi `body` y tengo lo siguiente:

```
<body>
  <header>
    <?= $this->_data['header']; ?>
  </header>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <footer>
    <?= $this->_data['footer']; ?>
  </footer>
  <?= $this->_data['adicionales']; ?>
  
  <!-- IMPORTACIONES DE SCRIPTS CON CDN --!>
</body>
```

Allí tengo mi `id app` que llamo con el primer `querySelector`

Comment: Con esto debería bastar `const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));` supongo que tienes un archivo `index.js` donde solo tienes a `ReactDOM.createRoot` y llamas a `root.render(<App />)`

Comment: Realice la edición de la pregunta acerca del index

Answer (score 1):

Dónde tienes el:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

Debés reemplazarlo por esto:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

De modo que en tu implementación quedaría así:

```
const App = () => {
  ///page/index/getInformationPage
  //levar la info de la pagina links redes sociales info footer
  const infoUrl = `page/index/getInformationPage`;
  const [infoPage, setInfoPage] = React.useState();

  const fetchInfoPage = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(infoUrl);

    const data = await response.json();

    setInfoPage(data);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchInfoPage();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter>
      <Navigation {...infoPage} />
      <Help />
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/contacto" exact component={Contacto} />
      <Route path="/convenios" exact component={Convenios} />
      <Route path="/nosotros" exact component={Nosotros} />
      <Route path="/portafolio" exact component={Portafolio} />
      <Route
        path="/portafolio/detalle/:section"
        exact
        component={PortafolioDetail}
      />
      <Route path="/sedes" exact component={Sedes} />
      <Route path="/pqrs" exact component={PqrsIndex} />
      <Route path="/noticias" exact component={NoticiaAll} />
      <Route
        path="/noticias/detail/:newDetail"
        exact
        component={NoticiaDetail}
      />
      <Footer {...infoPage} />
    </ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter>
  );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Recuerda incluir `React y ReactDOM` si es por CDN leé [esto](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html):

Comment: Realice la edición de la pregunta acerca del index.js

Comment: Disculpa, a qué te refieres?

Comment: Edite mi pregunta ya que tu solución no la puedo realizar o no se como realizarla con mi codigo como lo muestro en la pregunta

Comment: Ok, cambio mi respuesta

Comment: Al usar tu solución me sale el siguiente error `DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.`

Comment: Este error tambien esta saliendo `DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node. at insertInContainerBefore`

Answer (score 0):

Luego de revisar mi codigo varias veces me fije en una importación en el CDN que me estaba generando los problemas en mi aplicación

```
  <!-- <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script> -->
  <!-- <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script> -->
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@5.0.0/umd/react-router-dom.min.js'></script>
  <!-- <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script> -->
```

Los que estan comentados los tenia sin comentar y justo mas arriba de esos scripts tenia los siguientes activos tambie:

```
  <script crossorigin src="/react/js/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="/react/js/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="/react/js/babel.min.js"></script>
```

No estoy muy seguro pero a lo mejor al tener los 2 importados me estaba generando ese conflicto ya cuando los comente me funciono normalmente el `App` con el siguiente codigo y

```
const App = () => {
  ///page/index/getInformationPage
  //levar la info de la pagina links redes sociales info footer
  const infoUrl = `page/index/getInformationPage`;
  const [infoPage, setInfoPage] = React.useState();

  const fetchInfoPage = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(infoUrl);

    const data = await response.json();

    setInfoPage(data);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchInfoPage();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter>
      <Navigation {...infoPage} />
      <Help />
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/contacto" exact component={Contacto} />
      <Route path="/convenios" exact component={Convenios} />
      <Route path="/nosotros" exact component={Nosotros} />
      <Route path="/portafolio" exact component={Portafolio} />
      <Route
        path="/portafolio/detalle/:section"
        exact
        component={PortafolioDetail}
      />
      <Route path="/sedes" exact component={Sedes} />
      <Route path="/pqrs" exact component={PqrsIndex} />
      <Route path="/noticias" exact component={NoticiaAll} />
      <Route
        path="/noticias/detail/:newDetail"
        exact
        component={NoticiaDetail}
      />
      <Footer {...infoPage} />
    </ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter>
  );
};
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('#app')).render(<App />)
```